# MVC 3 Razor Engine and Html Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The Razor view engine automatically differentiates between Server code and Html Code
For example this code works very fine

```
@if (DateTime.Now.Year == 1983) 
{
  if (DateTime.Now.Month == 9) 
  {
    <p>Wow, this month Shay is born!</p>
  }
} 
else 
{
 <p>It's the new millenium dude!</p>
}
```

But if I want to show html tags or anchor tags in the text then what escape character should I use?

Like in the above example I want to show the else message like this

```
else 
{
 <p>It's the new <millenium> dude!</p>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
<p>It's the new &lt;millenium$gt; dude!</p>
```

But that's not a Razor issue, it's HTML. If you want to display `<` or `>` you have to use the  HTML entities instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular HTML escape sequences: `&lt;millenium&gt;`